# Local dimension of graph embedding

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, manifolds

I am trying to find a way to characterize the dimension of the smallest space into which a (neighbourhood of) a graph $\Gamma = (V, E)$ may be embedded. Although in the end my goal is to identify what real manifold ${\mathcal M}$ this graph could be the coarse-graining of, I am looking for a procedure without a priori knowledge of $\dim({\mathcal M})$. I would like it to be curvature-independent too.

Of course a graph may always be embedded at least in $3d$ space, but the resulting topology is most often overintricate and tells little about a simpler embedding manifold. Take, e.g. a $4d$ hypercubic lattice as your graph, it is not manifest in its $3d$ embedding that there is a simple embedding with $d=4$, and that it is a coarse-graining of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Moreover you may have graphs which different regions have different dimensionalities (e.g. simplicial complexes). In this case a "beyond local" definition of dimension - e.g. through ball-size scaling as a function of distance - is not adapted. For this reason, I am looking for local criteria : find the dimensionality at the vertex level (then I understand the embedding set may be richer than a manifold - but why not?).

Of course, at vertex $i \in V$ level, the incidence number $n_i$ is not enough to characterize the dimensionality. So I am trying to find a more complex criterion, based on the number $c_i$  of minimal non-trivial cycles that go through the vertex $i$. In this context one may imagine that a local meaning of dimensionality could be a level of  similarity between the local connectivity of the graph in question and that of  some regular coarse-graining graph of the embedding piece of manifold.

Looking in this direction, I found for hypercubic lattices in any dimension, as well as for compact-packing lattices in $d=2$ and $d=3$ that $c_i / n_i = d-1$. Of course this does not work with sparser lattices (e.g. Kagomé), but they don't look either like coarse grainings of even a piece of a regular manifold.

Now comes the question(s) for the patient readers who reached this point: I am a physicist not a mathematician as you may have guessed, and I have little background on this kind of topic. Could anyone tell me

- if this subject is/has been active?
- if there are results in this direction?
- if so, what is/are the main references?

Many thanks beforehands!

==>  **Addendum to answer Daniel Rust's comments**

Thanks Daniel for pointing at my inaccurate wording. I'll try to correct it as much as I can so that it becomes easier to understand.

- Coarse-graining - it is indeed a physicist's term - the way an object is seen with a coarser observation scale (e.g. a smooth sheet of paper when you can't see the atoms it's made of) - here I would like to see a manifold as a low-resolution view of an underlying graph, but you're right, this deserves a clean mathematical definition. It is the key idea here. I would like to try to define this embedding as $E : \Gamma \rightarrow {\mathcal M}$ where

  each vertex $i \in \Gamma$  is mapped to a point $P_i \in {\mathcal M}$ ,

  each edge $e_{ij} \in \Gamma $ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$ is mapped to a curve ${\mathcal C}_{ij} \subset {\mathcal M}$ with $P_i$ and $P_j$ as ends,

  the set of $e_{ij}$'s is homeomorphic to the set of ${\mathcal C}_{ij}$'s

  to constrain more the embedding manifold, one could add to this that the ${\mathcal C}_{ij}$ are geodesics with unit length on ${\mathcal M}$.
- Overintricate topology - It I want the graph to look like a smooth manifold from afar, I consider there must be some sort of coherence in the edge structure - for instance a square lattice could look like a $2d$ manifold, but if you add to it edges that connect vertices at random several cells away, you get a graph topology that is less likely to like a smooth manifold from afar.
- Neighbourhood - it is not key here. I meant a connected subgraph, built by selecting one vertex, taking all the vertices which have an edge to the selected one, and all the existing edges between those. [I have in mind such neighbourhoods that may require an embedding of a specific dimension - e.g. a simplex in a simplicial complex would require a $3d$ embedding if it's a tetrahedron and a $2d$ embedding only if it's a triangle. What I anticipate this way is actually an embedding by some object which is richer than a a manifold, as its dimension may change from place to place, so you can't just define it with a map on open sets in  $\mathbb{K}^d$ with fixed $d$.]

Comment: I'm not sure if I personally know enough to answer this question, but I do have a few questions. What is the 'neighbourhood' of a graph if it doesn't naturally come with an embedding into some space (one might assume $\mathbb{R}^3$, but then it makes your question moot). What is a coarse-graining? Is it possible this term is from physics and not graph theory/topology? What's an overintricate topology? Do you mean you want your embedding to be such that there is a neighbourhood of the image of every point in the graph which intersects the image of the graph in a space homemorphic to either

Comment: an open line segment, a half-open line segment, or a finite union of half-open line segments glued at their closed end points?

Comment: I'm not sure it is what your looking for but I'm following a course where we see how to embed metric spaces such as graphs into Banach spaces. The book we were recommended is ["Metric embeddings" by M. Ostrovskii](http://www.degruyter.com/view/product/177995?format=KOM).

Comment: Also, if you want you embedding to be isometric, note that a graph with more than 4 points does not necessarily embed isometrically in $\mathbb{E}^n$. Take for example the cycle $C_4$ composed of the vertices $a,b,c,d$, in your graph $d(a,c)=2=d(b,c)$ and $d(a,b)=d(b,c)=d(c,d)=d(a,d)=1$ (where $d$ is the distance in $C_4$). Then you cannot embed this graph in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and maintain all these distances. The best you can do is distort $d(a,c)$ and $d(b,d)$ to be $\sqrt{2}$ by putting $a$ at $(0,0)$, $b$ at $(1,0)$, $c$ at $(1,1)$ and $d$ at $(0,1)$.